# generate random varying length octal string

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography

i'm working on coding a implementation of Oaep for python and in some [docs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-7.1.1) it says that a need to generate a "random octet string seed of length h-len" i took this to mean i need a random octet string of a specific length.

when i tried looking around i could not seem to find anything on the subject. does anyone know how to do something like this. i have also tried a basic for loop that add appends to the string randomly but this also failed.

Comment: octet = byte (8 bits). octal = in octal base. Apples and origins. For example, `bytearray(random.randrange(256) for i in range(16))` creates an octet string of length 16.

Comment: @amadan thank you. not quite sure how i missed that

Comment: OAEP is a cryptographic algorithm; you'll need a cryptographically secure random number generator - by default `randrange` doesn't seem to claim any security properties.